# jpa 2.1 and new Date APi: YearMonth to Date Converter, MySQL Exception

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

I'm stack, I need to get the entries in a table (MySQL), using JPA 2.1, in a Java SE 8 client application, but I get this Exception:

```
[EL Warning]: 2015-05-18 13:57:15.882--UnitOfWork(974306870)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'YEAR_MONTH FROM app.INCOME WHERE (YEAR_MONTH = '2015-05-01 00:00:00')' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: SELECT ID, AMOUNT, PERIOD, SOURCE, YEAR_MONTH FROM app.INCOME WHERE (YEAR_MONTH = ?)
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Income sql="SELECT ID, AMOUNT, PERIOD, SOURCE, YEAR_MONTH FROM app.INCOME WHERE (YEAR_MONTH = ?)")
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse     Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'YEAR_MONTH FROM app.INCOME WHERE (YEAR_MONTH = '2015-05-01 00:00:00')' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: SELECT ID, AMOUNT, PERIOD, SOURCE, YEAR_MONTH FROM app.INCOME WHERE (YEAR_MONTH = ?)
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Income sql="SELECT ID, AMOUNT, PERIOD, SOURCE, YEAR_MONTH FROM app.INCOME WHERE (YEAR_MONTH = ?)")
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:382)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
```

here is the code

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="app")
public class Income implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    //partial: 2015-02      AUTO
    @Column(name="YEAR_MONTH")
    private YearMonth ymonth;

    private String source;

    private int amount;
```

Using this JPQL Query:

```
private static final String MONTH_INCOMES = "SELECT i FROM Income i WHERE i.ymonth = :month";
List<Income> sources= em.createQuery(MONTH_INCOMES, Income.class).setParameter("month", YearMonth.now()).getResultList();
```

I implemented this Converter: YearMonth <-> Date

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class YearMonthDateJPAConverter implements AttributeConverter<YearMonth, Date>{

@Override
public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(YearMonth entityValue) {
    return Date.from(entityValue.atDay(1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}

@Override
public YearMonth convertToEntityAttribute(Date dbValue) {
    return YearMonth.from(dbValue.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
}
```

The DB is MySQL 5.6, and the table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE `income` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `YEAR_MONTH` date NOT NULL,
  `SOURCE` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `AMOUNT` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PERIOD` enum('once','daily','weekly','twoWeeks','twiceAmonth','fourweeks','monthly','twoMonths','ev3month','ev4month','twiceAyear','yearly','twoYear') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and the table is empty. what's wrong with this????? I did not understand even the exception

Comment: I might be wrong (I dont do much mySQL these days), but it looks as if its being interpreted as a String?  What is the support like for java.time in JPA?

Comment: I don't know if I get the question right but, there is NO support, that's why you need to implement a converter to persist java.time classes

Comment: ah I see!  This may be a basic question, but you are scanning that package that contains your @Converter for annotations?

Comment: JPA does that work, in a client application (SE), you have to list the converter like any entity in persistence.xml, and that's why JPA convert automatically the type YearMonth to Date. just to let you know I even convert YearMonth to String, but Still the same exception!!

Comment: Tell me, what happens if you execute the generated query manually in your dbms?  SELECT ID, AMOUNT, PERIOD, SOURCE, YEAR_MONTH FROM app.INCOME WHERE (YEAR_MONTH = '2015-05-01 00:00:00')

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'YEAR_MONTH FROM app.INCOME WHERE (YEAR_MONTH = 2015-05)' at line 1

Comment: the same as you can see, note i change the year_month to varchar(100)

Comment: looks like you didn't wrap 2015-05 in quotes to make it a string?

Comment: and finally, it fixed, I change the names of two tables: 'YEAR_MONTH' and 'SOURCE', MySQL color them with same color as SELECT and alike words I should not name those table with these, why? I really don't know, now there is no problem no exception, thanks man a lot for you help.

Comment: aha so you gave your columns names of reserved words, which got jpa all confused.  Maybe you should post an answer detailing your findings for other users?  
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: done, right columns not tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: change the names of two columns: SOURCE, YEAR_MONTH. because they are reserved words by MySQL. No Java Problem, just colums naming